# Printing a list of numbers in python v.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python version 3.2.3. I am trying to print a list of numbers in a row, the print command seems to always printing the numbers one at row.

Example

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for num in numbers:
    print("\t ", num)
```

output is:

```
1

2
...
```

the required output is 1 2 3 4 5

I would appreciate your help.
P.s. I searched the web in here and most of the questions were related to Python 2.7.

Comment: There is a [python-3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag, which may help in your searches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `end` argument to suppress (or replace) the automatic EOL output:

```
print("\t ", num, end='')
```

Or, you should probably just use:

```
print('\t'.join(map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
```

Comment: There's an even easier way now that print is a function: `print(*numbers, sep='\t')`

Comment: @ThomasK Your comment is actually a very good answer, why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers, there's a neat way to do it now that print is a function:

```
print(*numbers, sep='\t')
```

Unlike your original code, this won't put a tab before the first number. If you want that extra tab, the easiest way is just to put a blank item before the numbers, so it creates an extra tab separator:

```
print('', *numbers, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.join()` to join them using the tab character:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print('\t'.join(map(str, numbers)))
1   2   3   4   5
```

`map(str, numbers)` is identical to `[str(n) for n in numbers]`.

Comment: `map(str, numbers)` is similar to `(str(n) for n in numbers)`, not what you've written.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()`, which will send your output to the output stream immediately, and without the newline.

This has the disadvantage of being ugly and the advantage of not storing your whole string in memory at once.  (The `join` approach would crash your computer if your array was very, very large.)

Comment: Change "crash your computer" to "crash your Python process".